# Identity Server 4 Angular 2 token expiration

Tags: angular, oauth, openid-connect, identityserver4

I'm looking for advice on how best to handle token expiration with  Angular 2 and Identity Server 4. I'm using the implicit flow with Identity Server 4 which doesn't issue refresh tokens and I don't want to have to redirect the user after the token expires.

Also, why isn't there a refresh token? Why won't hybrid flow work for javascript clients? I do control the ID Server, the app and the api so would this work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I can recommend the library for managing token for the javascript application:
https://github.com/IdentityModel/oidc-client-js

You've correctly used the implicit flow for SPA - here is the description about which flow is right one - https://leastprivilege.com/2016/01/17/which-openid-connectoauth-2-o-flow-is-the-right-one/

`Oidc-client` provides great feature called `automaticSilentRenew` - [check the docs](https://github.com/IdentityModel/oidc-client-js/wiki). There is the timer on the background and handle an event before token expiration and using hidden iframe for getting new access token.

Example for `Angular2` and `oidc-client`:
https://github.com/jmurphzyo/Angular2OidcClient

Video with overview for authentication and authorization in JavaScript web applications using IdentityServer - https://vimeo.com/131636653

Comment: yee but if the browser is closed then silent refreshing is not working.